# Why am I getting an error message when trying to "wipe" my micro-sd card using dd command?

Tags: linux, command, dd

**Purpose**: wipe entire sd card, not just 'delete'

Command:(umounted)

```
"sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=8192"

dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device

118139+0 records in
118138+0 records out
```

There are files on the sd. First, I opened a terminal where the sd card was, and ran the command, and then opened a separate terminal in a different location, and ran the command; same result.

**UPDATE**: I noticed that the sd will not let me delete the partition on it. I used "sudo fdisk /dev/sda". "no partition yet defined".

**UPDATE 2**: I restarted the computer and was (then) able to delete the partition. I'm currently trying the wipe again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal was opening in "media" and for some reason, even after closing all terminals, and opening one from the file manager, it kept opening in 'media'. I restarted the computer and that fixed it. I was able to wipe the card then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That error is normal in this context, and just means that it's done. `/dev/urandom` is infinite and your microSD card isn't. You're getting that error because `dd` wanted to write more data to it, but ran out of room (because the whole thing was already wiped). If you'd like more assurance than this, you can use the `shred` command instead, which is better designed for this and won't cause an error.

Comment: at joseph - thanks, but it didn't wipe the files that were on there. If you know of a "shred" command, please share it.

Comment: @topencrypt 1. Are you sure you got the right device? 2. Did you do that with it still mounted (which you shouldn't have done)? And the command is literally called `shred`.

Comment: at joseph - I don't think it was mounted; I used the command stated above, not 'shred'; yes, the right device for sure.

Comment: So to clarify, you unmounted it, ran the `dd`, then remounted it, and still saw the files?

Comment: at joseph - correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you really used `/dev/sdx` then you have almost certainly just created a large file on your `/dev` partition. In this situation the "out of space" error will be relating to the partition rather than your intended device, and you'll want to delete the unintended *file* `/dev/sdx`.

Verify that it's a file with `find /dev/sdx -type f`. You'll get output if it is a file but no output otherwise (i.e. it's probably a device).

If you didn't really use `/dev/sdx` but instead used the correct device node, please edit your question to show this, and advise us how you identified the correct device. (And I'll delete this answer.)

Finally, make sure the device was unmounted before trying to overwrite the underlying device. Otherwise you may find that cached blocks of data are written back to the device, resulting in a semblance of the a filesystem being present.